# Mapview refresh not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mkmapview, ios4

I'm showing the route between 2 places. My project is a navigation based project. In the `viewWillAppear:` method I track the current location of the user using location manager. In the 
`- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation` method I get the coordinates of the user's current location.

I draw the map with this. Now when I get back to the previous view and come back map view it doesn't load the user location. It doesnt call `- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation` method.

How can I rectify this? I need to get the map route everytime I come to this class.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you seeing this problem on the device or in the simulator? The simulator doesn't always issue regular location updates.

Comment: in simulator only. the current location it show is cupertino. that s k but second time i click the "Map" button it doesnt upload the location again.

Answer (score 0):

I am about to answer my own question with this as well:

I saw posts on how to reset the view, redraw the layer etc. I am fairly (not new) inexperienced with the language, so what I have done is a hack, but it works. I hope you use this if you have to, but find a better solution.

View Controller:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    mapView.region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance([mapView centerCoordinate],2587600.0, 2587600.0);

}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    mapView.region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance([mapView centerCoordinate],5.0, 5.0);
}
```

So when the view leaves, well... view, then the map zooms really far in. When the view returns to view, the the data is reloaded and voila. Your mileage may vary, but this method works perfectly for what I need it to do.

And it is not a jarring effect at all. It is seamless. From a UI standpoint, nothing changes.

cheers!
Robert